# How to POST action REST API in Yii2 Advanced Template

Tags: php, api, vue.js, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i Have a question for you guys :) I'm trying to add an API on my yii2 advanced template as i want my wordpress website send datas to my yii2 app. 
My system : 1) Yii2 advanced template 2) wordpress website 3) my wordpress plugin with vuejs and axios to create a new entry in my yii2 app via API
So what i allready did : 
common/config/main.php (as i use AccessController, i added orders/* to allow it)

```
'as access' => [
'class' => 'mdm\admin\components\AccessControl',
'allowActions' => [
    'orders/*',
],
```

frontend/config/main.php

```
'components' => [
'request' => [
    'parsers' => [
        'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
    ],
```

and (in urlManager array)

```
['class'=>'yii\rest\UrlRule','controller'=>'Orders'],
[‘class'=>'yii\rest\UrlRule','controller'=>'Contacts']
```

Then my controller :

```
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController; use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;
class OrdersController extends ActiveController {
public $modelClass = 'common\models\Vctorders';

public function behaviors()
{
$behaviors = parent::behaviors();

// remove authentication filter
$auth = $behaviors['authenticator'];
unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

// add CORS filter
$behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
    'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
];

// re-add authentication filter
$behaviors['authenticator'] = $auth;
// avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
$behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];

return $behaviors;
}

public function actions()
{
$actions = parent::actions();
unset($actions['create']);
unset($actions['update']);
unset($actions['delete']);
unset($actions['view']);
//unset($actions['index']);
return $actions;
}

protected function verbs(){
return [
    'create' => ['POST'],
    'new' => ['POST'],
    'update' => ['PUT', 'PATCH','POST'],
    'delete' => ['DELETE'],
    'view' => ['GET'],
    //'index'=>['GET'],
];
}


public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Vctorders();

    $model->date_creation = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('now'));
    $model->etat = 0;
    if($model->save()){ 
      return 'OK';

   } else{
      return 'error';
   }


}


}
```

So, i a use Postman with : http://localhost:8888/SD/sdms/orders/ i get a record, no problem

But when i do a POST with :

```
http://localhost:8888/SD/sdms/orders/create?livre=L'Arbre Musicien&langue=Allemand&nom=Perroud&prenom=LIttledave&nombre=2&npa=1221&pays=suisse&accept_pc=1&mail=post@post.ch&etat=1&message=lbablalbal&tel=01201201212
```

the answer is

```
{"name":"Exception","message":"Class 'frontend\\controllers\\Vctorders' not found","code":0,"type":"Error","file":"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SD/sdms/frontend/controllers/OrdersController.php","line":58,"stack-trace":["#0 [internal function]: frontend\\controllers\\OrdersController->actionCreate()","#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SD/sdms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)","#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SD/sdms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\\base\\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)","#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SD/sdms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): yii\\base\\Controller->runAction('create', Array)","#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SD/sdms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): yii\\base\\Module->runAction('orders/create', Array)","#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SD/sdms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\\web\\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\\web\\Request))","#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SD/sdms/frontend/web/index.php(17): yii\\base\\Application->run()","#7 {main}"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are sending your request in `POSTMAN` as a `GET REQUEST`, and your `ACTION` in the `CONTROLLER` expects a `POST REQUEST`.

In your POSTMAN client at the left side, there is a selector where you can choose what kind of request you are doing.

The second error you get is because once you remove the requisite of POST, the GET request enters the `action` and goes here:

```
} elseif (!\Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
   $model->load(Yii::$app->request->get());
}
```

And tries to load the model with the data in the `GET` parameters, but fails as there is no way the default `$model->load()` knows how to map the data in your GET petition.

In any case (GET or POST) the `$model->load()` will not work, as if you check the load() function you will find that it searches for the Object modal name inside the array to load the parameters, so you must do like:

```
http://localhost:8888/SD/sdms/orders/create?Orders%5Blivre%5=L'Arbre
```

But for each parameter, the strange characters you see in the result of stringify `['Orders' => ['livre' => 'Larbre']]`.

Comment: Hey, thank's for your answer !
But i'm sending from Postman with POST and not with GET, so i don't understand what you say about a first error, because i said, with the get, i receive the record, no problem, but when i do a POST sending with Postman, i get the 2 things i wrote.

Comment: And as i stupidly copy/paste my create function from my backend controller, i changed it (i modified my post so its clearer to see) but i still get the same error